# React Native - Two Apps Bar Being Display in One Screen

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

My issue is I tried to implement 2 type of Nagivation Type in my Apps, TabNavigation and StackNavigation, so I using a root StackNavigator, which has one route to myTabNavigator and one to my other StackNavigator(Code Snippet of App.js). However, when I navigate to **View Screen which is SecondActivity.js** there will be two header pop out. I try to use `header:null` on SecondActivity.js but it will cause both header gone.

Is there any way to remove only 1 of the header from the SecondActivity.js Screen?

[image]
**App.js (using RootNavigator to combine Tab and Stack Navigation in this Apps)**

```
const App = TabNavigator({
 HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
 ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreen },
}, {
     tabBarOptions: {
       activeTintColor: '#7567B1',
       labelStyle: {
       fontSize: 16,
       fontWeight: '600'
       }
     }
   });

const Go = StackNavigator({
 First: { screen: ProfileScreen },
 Second: { screen: SecondActivity }
});

const rootNav = StackNavigator({
 app: {screen: App},
 go: {screen: Go},
});

export default rootNav;
```

**ProfileScreen.js**

```
 static navigationOptions = {
   tabBarLabel: 'View/Edit', 
   header: null
 }

 // This Line Used to Navigate to SecondActivity.js Screen
 OpenSecondActivity(id) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', { ListViewClickItemHolder: id });
 }

 // The ListView onPress will call the function above.
 <ListView
           automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}

              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}

              renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparator}

              renderRow={(rowData) => <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer}
              onPress={this.OpenSecondActivity.bind(this, rowData.RecipeID)}> {rowData.RecipeName} </Text>}

            />
```

**SecondActivity.js**

```
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'View Details',
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Each StackNavigator has its own header.
- this is happening you are using nested stackNavigator, so one header is because of Go (stackNavigator), and another one is because of rootNav (stackNavigator).
- The `Go StackNavigation` is unnecessary instead change the rootNav into this:

```js
const App = TabNavigator({
 HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
 ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreen },
}, {
     tabBarOptions: {
       activeTintColor: '#7567B1',
       labelStyle: {
       fontSize: 16,
       fontWeight: '600'
       }
     }
   });


const rootNav = StackNavigator({
 app: {screen: App},
  First: { screen: ProfileScreen },
 Second: { screen: SecondActivity }

});

export default rootNav;
```

Comment: sir, do you mean by putting this? 

static navigationOptions = {
   header: null
 }

Comment: No  putting header:null in navigationOption of  component class will hide both the header . You need put this in stacknavigator config ...read React-navigation prop for more understanding

Comment: const Go = StackNavigator({ 
    First: { screen: ProfileScreen },
    Second: { screen: SecondActivity } 
},
{ 
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal', 
    navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
        header:null 
    }
});

Comment: Like this you can add

Comment: the affect will remove all the header in the screen somehow, still can't understand why when trying to explicit remove only the stack navigation header, turn out both tab and stack navigation header will be remove in the same time.

Comment: first of all why you want to nest one stackNavigator into other , when you just add more routes to rootNav

Comment: actually what i trying to do just apply 2 navigation (tab and stack) to a single apps, that all. Am i doing it the wrong way?

Comment: I achieve the same thing, by only one stackNavigator and one TabNavigator, used tabNavigator inside stackNavigator. that's exactly you are doing except one extra stackNavigator (Go) copy screen from Go and paste it to rootNav StackNavigator.

Comment: Thanks For your Clear Explanation. The root issue begin with Exactly what you mentioned.

I change my rootNav to this, everything solved:

const rootNav = StackNavigator({
     app: {screen: App},
     First: { screen: ProfileScreen },
     Second: { screen: SecondActivity }  
});

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the fact that the tab navigator is being rendered within the stack navigator.

Create a util file, and put this method on it. It resets the stack and put tab navigator on top

```
const resetActivities = (navigation, rootPath,props) => {

const stackAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key: null,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: rootPath,params:props })],
});
navigation.dispatch(stackAction);
}
```

and pass the 'App', and the navigation object

Comment: Sir, what do you mean by 'pass the 'App', and the navigation object' ?

Comment: when you call this function, pass the name of the screen, and the navigation object itself, in this case the name of the Screen is 'App'

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get it, could you provide me a code snippet on how to apply what you mentioned above?

Comment: ok, when you call the this.props.navigation.navigate('App'), that i think you do,change it to resetActivities(this.props.navigation,'App'), this will change the screen and reset the stack.

Comment: in my case I didn't have use the this.props.navigation.navigate('App') in my whole program, to use that code where should I put the code to?

Comment: can you post more code so? cant understand your navigation logic

Comment: I updated my code, i using this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', { ListViewClickItemHolder: id }); to navigate to the other screen. So that I could pass the ListView Iterm ID to the other screen for fetch Data purpose.

Comment: ok, im back, when you call this.props.navigate, call my method instead, and you can add a new parameter called props, and use it on navigate action